# Iterating json data from an Api

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have an api from which I want to display the data, I have 2 arrays I think each one has `category` how would I iterate and display these 2 categories, so category `Arts` and category `Entertainment`.I would really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import './Home.css'
import Books from './Books'
const url="https://json-api-smaiil.herokuapp.com/books"


const Home = () => {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([])

    const fetchData =async()=>{
    setLoading(true)
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const books = await response.json()
    console.log(books)
    setBooks(books)
    }

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData();
  },[])
  


    return (
        <div>
          <h1 className='categories'>Categories</h1>
           {books[0].map((book)=>{
             return <li key={book.id}>{book.category}</li>
           })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home

[
     "Arts":[{
    "category": "Arts"
    Language: "English"
    Narrated by: "Faith G. Harper PhD LPC-S ACS ACN"
    Regular price: "$17.47"
    Release date: "03-20-18"
    bookName: "Unf--k Your Brain"
    by: "Faith G. Harper PhD LPC-S ACS ACN"
    category: "Arts and Entertainment"
    id: "1"
},
{

    Language: "English"
    Length: "1 hr and 33 mins"
    Narreted by: "James Taylor"
    Regular price: "$9.95"
    Release date: "01-31-20"
    Series: "Words + Music"
    bookName: " Break Shot: My First 21 Years"
    by: "James Taylor"
    id: "2"
}],

    "Entertainment":[{   
    "category" :"Entertainment"
    "id": "9",
    "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51tpSb0iy+L._SL500_.jpg",
    "bookName": "The Hiding Place",
    "by": "Corrie ten Boom, John Sherrill, Elizabeth Sherrill",
    "Narreted by": "Wanda McCaddon",
    "Length": "8 hrs and 14 mins",
    "Release date": "10-03-11",
    "Language": "English",
    "rating": "6,641 ratings",
    "Regular price": "$24.95",
  
},

{
    Language: "English"
    Length: "1 hr and 7 mins"
    Narreted by: "Aidan Gillen"
    Regular price: "$9.95"
    Release date: "03-31-15"
    bookName: "The Art of War"
    by: "Sun Tzu"
    id: "12"   
    rating: "19,765 ratings"
 
}]
]
```

Comment: Please post what your actual data is; what you show here is not valid data.

Comment: @Dave Newton How do you mean, Api is broken?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation, but it looks like you're using map wrong.

Array.prototype.map's callback takes in `currentValue`, `index`, and `array` [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as arguments.  You can get the `id`, and `category` from the `currentValue` by *destructuring* (notice the curly brackets):

```js
//...
books[0].map(({id, category}) => {
//...
```

Comment: it displays this "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: that means `books[0]` is `undefined`. what does `books.Arts` look like?

Comment: TypeError: books.Arts is not a function

Comment: I meant with the `map`. `books.Arts` probably just gets the array, you cant call a function on an array. Try something like `books["Arts"].map(...)`

Comment: @ChanYoun You can call a function on an array; that's what "map" os :) Can't call a function on null, though.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined